# How to install a Python Windows service using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, windows, service, cx-freeze

I currently have a Python file that when run using python file_name.py installs a Windows service that is viewable in Event Viewer under application logs and stoppable using sc stop service_name. However, when converted into an executable using cx_Freeze, the executable runs with no errors but the service no longer installs. This happens if I run just the executable by itself, if I run service_name.exe --install service_name, or if I run sc create service_name binPath=service_path

My setup.py file looks something like:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

options = {
'build_exe': {
    'packages': ['packagename'],
    'includes': ['ServiceHandler', 'cx_Logging']}
}

setup(name='cx_FreezeSampleService',
  version='0.1',
  description='Sample cx_Freeze Windows serice',
  executables=Executable('Config.py', base='Win32Service',
           targetName='cx_FreezeSampleService.exe'),
  options=options
  )
```

My Config.py looks something like:

```
NAME = 'cx_FreezeSampleService%s'
DISPLAY_NAME = 'cx_Freeze Sample Service - %s'
MODULE_NAME = 'ServiceHandler'
CLASS_NAME = 'Handler'
DESCRIPTION = 'Sample service description'
AUTO_START = True
SESSION_CHANGES = False
```

And finally, my ServiceHandler.py looks something like:

```
class Handler(object):
 def Initialize(self, Config):
    pass

 def Run(self):
    #code to run service

 def Stop(self):
    #code to stop service
```

This code follows the example at the cx_Freeze source code here (https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/1282b6b6ee637738210113dd88c3c198d475340f/cx_Freeze/samples/service/?at=default) almost exactly, but neither this nor the example seem to work in actually installing a service.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found there is error in the cx_Freezes examples. The functions: `initialize, run, stop` must be defined with lower case. The service itself is registered for example with `cx_FreezeSampleService.exe --install test`

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I manage to get it working as a window service for a simple flask application with the help of the developers.
[https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/tree/master/cx_Freeze/samples/service]

You have to set up all the windows service actions you want performance.
this is how the  ServiceHandler.py should look like as a template you still need to adapt to run your application.

```
"""
Implements a simple service using cx_Freeze.
See below for more information on what methods must be implemented and how they
are called.
"""

import threading
import os
import sys
import cx_Logging




class Handler:

    # no parameters are permitted; all configuration should be placed in the
    # configuration file and handled in the Initialize() method
    def __init__(self):
        self.stopEvent = threading.Event()
        self.stopRequestedEvent = threading.Event()

    # called when the service is starting
    def initialize(self, configFileName):
        self.directory = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        cx_Logging.StartLogging(os.path.join(self.directory, "teste.log"), cx_Logging.DEBUG)
        #pass

    # called when the service is starting immediately after Initialize()
    # use this to perform the work of the service; don't forget to set or check
    # for the stop event or the service GUI will not respond to requests to
    # stop the service
    def run(self):
        cx_Logging.Debug("stdout=%r", sys.stdout)
        sys.stdout = open(os.path.join(self.directory, "stdout.log"), "a")
        sys.stderr = open(os.path.join(self.directory, "stderr.log"), "a")
        self.stopRequestedEvent.wait()
        self.stopEvent.set()

    # called when the service is being stopped by the service manager GUI
    def stop(self):
        self.stopRequestedEvent.set()
        self.stopEvent.wait()
```

Comment: Just a small correction. The `executables` argument should be a list of `Executable` objects.
Other than that - it worked like a magic :)
Thanks